# JSTL for each problem

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a for each loop that it works fine when the items property is filled using an scriplet in the following way:

```
<%
    List<LandingCategory> cats = beanFactory.getLandingCategories();
%>

<c:forEach var="cat" items="<%=cats%>">
    <c:out value="${cat.id}"/>          
</c:forEach>
```

However, when trying to filled the items list with a param specified in another jsp file, the for each will not work.

```
JSP1
<jsp:include page="/jsp/modules/index/index_categories.jsp">    
    <jsp:param name="categories" value="<%=cats%>"/>
</jsp:include>

JSP2
<c:forEach var="cat" items="${param.categories}">
    <c:out value="${cat.id}"/>          
</c:forEach>
```

The following error is thrown:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: Unable to find a value for "id" in object of class "java.lang.String" using operator "."
```

It seems that it is considering the objects  of the items list to be Strings, but I've no clue about why this is happening.

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Commenting rather than answering because this is just a guess, but: since a `<jsp:param>` is a name-value pair and the value is expected to be a string, I think your problem might be that you're coercing your entire list down to a single string. Is there a way for you to parse that string back out to a List, or to pull it in as a List directly rather than as the value of a parameter?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!
I finally went for skaffman answer and it worked fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<jsp:param>` tag provides a way of emulating the sort of parameters that you would pass in from an HTTP request. As such, they are Strings. So what `JSP1` is doing is taking your "cats" collection, converting it into a `String` (using `toString()`), and then passing that String as a parameter to `JSP2`.The foreach is then trying to iterate over that string. The `Cat` data structure was lost in translation.

What you need to do instead is to store the cats object as a request-scoped attribute, which will allow JSP2 to retrieve it:

```
<%
    List<LandingCategory> cats = beanFactory.getLandingCategories();
%>
<c:set var="cats" scope="request" value="<%=cats%>"/>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/modules/index/index_categories.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that

```
<jsp:param name="categories" value="<%=cats%>"/>
```

is causing toString() to be called on cats.  Use a tag file for this instead, it works better:

```
<yourTags:fileName cats='${cats}' />
```

instead.